# Using Leaflet/MarkerCluster/Label, how do I prevent the 'onclick' from firing when adding a marker?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have the following code for adding markers to a Leaflet based map:

```
// In function Init()
markers = L.markerClusterGroup(); // markers is Global

// In function addMarker()
var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(lat,lon), {icon: myIcon})
    .bindLabel(name, {noHide: true,direction: 'right'});
marker._myId = name;

marker.on('click',alert(marker._myId));
markers.addLayer(marker);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Without the 'on click' event registered everything works well and as expected.  When I add the line of code for to register the event it fires when adding the marker but does not fire when clicking the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the marker.on function solved the problem.  I don't know why you need to have the intermediary function but it works.

Instead of this:

```
marker.on('click',alert(marker._myId));
```

do this:

```
marker.on('click',onMarkerClick);
```

and this:

```
function onMarkerClick(e) {
    alert(e.target._myId);
}
```